# Can "Crabs Adjust Humidity" be used as an expansion to "Cards Against Humanity"?

Tags: cards-against-humanity

[Crabs Adjust Humidity](http://www.crabsadjusthumidity.com/) is a cardgame just like [Cards Against Humanity](http://www.cardsagainsthumanity.com/)

Can the cards be shuffled and used as an expansion pack? Or are there other differences which prevent this?

(PS: Are they equally fun? Or should I just refrain from buying Crabs Adjust Humidity?)

Comment: AFAIK they have different card backs, but it wouldn't be much of concern to me. It is barely a "game", so this shouldn't affect "gameplay" much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have both Crabs against Humidity and Guards against Insanity. They can be mixed with Cards against Humanity. They have different backs but that is not a real problem.

Personally, I think the original (and the original expansions 1 to 6) are better. I use the following arguments:

1. A lot of the unofficial expansion cards are probably targetted to the younger public and as such have a lot of references to sex and nudity.
2. Some white cards have a limited use.
3. A lot of black cards have 2 or three blanks so you run out of white cards fast.
4. Some cards are almost duplicates of cards from the original series.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as it's billed as an "unofficial expansion to Cards Against Humanity" ([see website](http://www.crabsadjusthumidity.com/)), I think the answer must be "yes". That said, it does appear the card backs are different, so you may need to slap everything into opaque-back sleeves to make it work really well.

Comment: Alternatively, you could imbibe sufficient alcohol so you no longer tell the difference. Not cheaper than sleeves, but more fun.